# Pass string[] textbox to controller and get ID for each textbox MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I am passing a list from my controller to my view, and then inside a form I loop through each list item and display a table with some textboxes that need to be filled in for each item.

What I then want to do is submit the data back to my controller, look through it to grab the results of what was entered, and save to database.

How do I do this??  I have put my code below

### CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult GetListOfDogs()
{
var list = db.dogs;  //gets multiple dogs 
return View(dogs);

///Dog object looks like this
///int Id 
///string DogName 
///string RegNumber 
///string Breed 
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveDogInfo(string[] RegNumber, string[] Breed)
{

}
```

### VIEW

```
GetListOfDogs.cshtml

@model Dog

@using(Html.BeginForm("SaveDogInfo", "Dog", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Reg Number</th>
        <th>Breed</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.DogName</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("RegNum", null, new{id = "dId_=" + @item.Id})</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("Breed", null, new{id = "breed_=" + @item.Id})</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<input type="Submit" value="Save" />
```

}

Inside my 'SaveDogInfo' action, I can view the results for RegNumber and Breed, but there is no id coming back with them, so I have no way of matching the result with the actual DogId it belongs to..

Can anyone help or am I just totally missing the point???

Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model of your view should be something enumerable, no ?

```
@model IList<Dog>
```

then use a for loop, and **add an hidden field** for Id. !

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) 
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Name</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].RegNumber)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Breed)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
           </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

then your post action should become

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveDogInfo(IEnumerable<Dog> dogs)
{

}
```

Comment: yeah sorry it is @model IEnumerable<Dog>

Comment: I have modified my view to use the for loop, and looking at the source, I can see that the Id has been put into the hidden field.  On my controller I have also changed it to expect IEnumerable<Dog>, but when I put a breakpoint to view what is inside dogs, I am getting dogs is null

Comment: Ok... so I have got it working now... <br />I had to make a couple of changes... <br />Using IEnumerable<Dog> I was getting an error when trying to index the row (@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>Model[i].)) it turns out you cannot apply indexing to type IEnumerable, so instead I tried to use @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>Model.ElementAt(i).property) and that allowed the text box to display correctly, however it was then that I was getting the null being returned to the controller... <br /> So I went back to the original idea of using Model[i], but chnaged my type to IList<> and now it is working correctly.

Comment: @jonahpup yes, I corrected in same way just now, sorry for that.

Comment: that's all good... I appreciate the help, at least it got me on the right track